# What are the basic assumptions for a line integral to exist?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For line integrals of scalar fields and vector fields over a curve(everything in $\mathbb{R}^n$, what are the weakest assumptions for their existence?

For whatever reason my book don't go into much detail on this.